# Android mediaplayer stops playing after 2 minutes (in foreground service)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mediaplayer, foreground-service

I am trying to implement media player, but it stops after 2 minutes of playtime - like it is not in foreground service. The foreground service starts from fragment and it should live only while the fragment is created.

Could someone help, please?

Service:

```
class MediaPlayerForegroundService : Service()  {

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        startForeground(1, notificationToDisplayServiceInform(), FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PLAYBACK)

        lockCpu()

        fileName = intent?.getStringExtra("fileName")

        handler = Looper.myLooper()?.let { Handler(it) }

        player = MediaPlayer().apply {
            setWakeMode(applicationContext, PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK)
        }

        player!!.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true)

        val afd: AssetFileDescriptor = applicationContext.assets.openFd(fileName!!)
        player!!.setDataSource(afd.fileDescriptor, afd.startOffset, afd.length);
        afd.close()

        player!!.setOnPreparedListener {
            handler!!.postDelayed(runnableCheck!!, 200)
        }

        player!!.prepareAsync()

        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    private fun createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val serviceChannel = NotificationChannel(
                channelId,
                "Foreground Service Channel",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            )
            val manager = getSystemService(
                NotificationManager::class.java
            )
            manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel)
        }
    }

    private fun notificationToDisplayServiceInform(): Notification {
        createNotificationChannel()
        val notificationIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this,
            0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE
        )
        return NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
            .setContentTitle("Simple Foreground Service")
            .setContentText("Explain about the service")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.player_play)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build()
    }

    private fun lockCpu() {
        wakeLock =
            (getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager).run {
                newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "Movapp::WakeLockFairyTale").apply {
                    acquire()
                }
            }
    }

}
```

Fragment code:

```
class PlayerFragment : Fragment() {


    private fun startMediaPlayerService(fileName: String){
        Intent(context, MediaPlayerForegroundService::class.java).also {
            it.putExtra("fileName", fileName)
        }.also {
            context!!.startForegroundService(it)
        }
    }


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
...
....
        startMediaPlayerService("stories/${slug}/${langPair.to.langCode}.mp3")

        return root
    }


    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()

        stopMediaPlayerService()

        _binding = null
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="cz.movapp.app">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>

    <application
        <service android:name=".MediaPlayerForegroundService"
            android:foregroundServiceType="mediaPlayback"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I tried a lot of googling, read several articles, and I have no clue why it stops right after two minutes. My android is version 13. In emulator, it works. If I set the `player.isLooping = true`, it plays the 2 minutes in a loop, which means the service lives.

**EDITED:**
I think I am a bit closer. Seems like the problem is in:

```
        val afd: AssetFileDescriptor = applicationContext.assets.openFd(fileName!!)
        player!!.setDataSource(afd.fileDescriptor, afd.startOffset, afd.length);
        afd.close()
```

The afd.length seems to be incorrect. afd.declaredLength is also too short (the same). This happens with more than one file.

I still do not know how to fix it.

**EDITED2:**
The problem with 2 minutes limit seems to be only for mp3 files with a bitrate lower than 96kbps. I can also say .ogg files work fine. Based on the documentation, the spec: [Mono/Stereo 8-320Kbps constant (CBR) or variable bit-rate (VBR)](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats) is supported. Is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that this is a bug. Have you experienced this problem on a Pixel device? I have seen some Pixel devices that had this behavior while it worked fine on other phones.

Comment: Yes, the affected device is the Pixel phone running Android 13. Thank you for your info. I still did not fix this bug... I guess the ogg file would be a suitable solution then.

Comment: Did you try using `AssetFileDescriptor.UNKNOWN_LENGTH` instead of `afd.length`?

Comment: Thank you but with `AssetFileDescriptor.UNKNOWN_LENGTH` the file will not play at all.

Comment: I think this worked for me. However, I am not able to reproduce this on my Pixel with Android 13 anyway. I would therefore assume that it is a bug in MediaPlayer that occurs only on some Pixel devices. I would suggest that you report this bug to Google.

Comment: Is it possible that Google has fixed this problem on the Pixel phones with a software update in the meantime?